# MySQL returning multiple entries when only one match exists (one display incorrect URL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a fairly simple database with only one table which contains the contact info for Texas Courts. The search form allows users to select that type of court and then enter the city or county name (seperate fields) they wish to search for.

The code:

```
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM COURTS
                      WHERE Type = '$_POST[Type]' AND City LIKE '$_POST[City]' 
                      OR Type = '$_POST[Type]' AND County LIKE '$_POST[County]'
                      ORDER BY County, City")

or die(mysql_error()); ?>

<table id="customers">
<?php while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)): ?>
<tr class="alt">
<td><?php echo $rows[Court]; ?>&nbsp<?php echo $rows[Type]; ?><br></td>
<td><?php echo $rows[City]; ?>,&nbsp<?php echo $rows[State]; ?><br></td>
<td><?php echo "<a href=$rows[URL]>Court Info</a>"; ?><br></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

When searching for a city whose name is different from the county name (eg. Boerne, Kendall County), MySQL returns two results for the city when only one exists in the table. The first return has a hyperlink to the current search result page and the second links to the proper information page. If a city shares its name with the county (eg. Bandera, Bandera County) the return is correct - one listing with the proper URL.

I have tried grouping, ordering and crying, but nothing works.

Edit:

Adding paranthesis still produces the same problem...

```
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM COURTS
                      WHERE (Type = '$_POST[Type]' AND City LIKE '$_POST[City]') 
                      OR (Type = '$_POST[Type]' AND County LIKE '$_POST[County]')
                      ORDER BY County, City")
```

Edit: Table Structure...

```
+--------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
|     Type     |    Court     |  County  |  Street   |  City   | State |  Zip  |     Email     |   Website    |  Phone   |     URL      |
+--------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
| Justice of.. | Precinct 1.. | Anderson | P O Box.. | Elkhart | TX    | 75839 | gthomas@co... | http://www.. | 903-76.. | http://www.. |
+--------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
```

And the result when a City name doesn't match its County's name:

```
+-------------------+-------------+------------+
| Boerne Municipal  | Boerne, TX  | Court Info | <<Court info links to the wrong URL (current page)
+-------------------+-------------+------------+
| Boerne Municipal  | Boerne, TX  | Court Info | <<Court Info links to correct URL
+-------------------+-------------+------------+
```

The above results are for the city of Boerne which has only one municipal court entry in the database.

Comment: If your query returns two rows, that means there are two rows that satisfy the `where` condition. Grouping, ordering, or crying doesn't help.  Show the complete table structure for `COURTS` and an example of the entire result form a query with two rows (all columns).  And indicate which of the two rows should be kept.

Comment: Show all the columns in the result, with column names, especially `county` and `city`.   You MUST have two rows in your table.

Comment: This clause ((Type = '$_POST[Type]' AND County LIKE '$_POST[County]')) will return all cities in your chosen county, which in this case is 2.

Comment: Just show all the columns returned by your query that has two rows; the answer will probably be obvious.  Your use of the `LIKE` clause is probably the issue, but it's hard to tell from your description;  seeing the data will reveal all.

Comment: Bob you were correct. Somehow after I truncated the table to re-import the data, some data remained in the table. I searched the source for duplicates not the active database. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you need paranthesis...

```
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM COURTS
                      WHERE (Type = '$_POST[Type]' AND City LIKE '$_POST[City]') 
                      OR (Type = '$_POST[Type]' AND County LIKE '$_POST[County]')
                      ORDER BY County, City")
```

Comment: Adding parenthesis still produces the same problem.